# What is the provenance of Story 6 in Day 2 of the Decameron, set against a backdrop of 13th-century Sicily?

Tags: history-of-literature, inspiration, italian-language, giovanni-boccaccio, decameron

[Day 2, Story 6](https://www.brown.edu/Departments/Italian_Studies/dweb/texts/DecShowText.php?myID=nov0206&expand=empty&lang=eng) of the Decameron is set against a political backdrop of 13th-century Sicily: it begins with the defeat of King [Manfred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manfred,_King_of_Sicily) at [Benevento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Benevento) by the new king [Charles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_I_of_Naples), and the main characters are the family of Manfred's ally Arrighetto Capece (then governor of Sicily): his wife Beritola Caracciola and son Giusfredi, and a younger son named Outcast (Scacciato). The story ends after the [War of the Sicilian Vespers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_of_the_Sicilian_Vespers), when Charles is deposed and Arrighetto comes back into favour and power in Sicily after a long imprisonment.

**What is the origin or provenance of this story?** Is it based on a true story (certainly the historical background is factual)? Does it have any known antecedent in recorded literature? I found a [19th-century opera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrighetto) about the same Arrighetto Capece, but of course that's much later and based on the Decameron story.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what Vittore Branca explains in the Einaudi version of the *Decameron* (Italian original) about the antecedents of this novella:

> Neppure di questa novella si possono indicare antecedenti precisi e significativi. Sono state a volta a volta citate la leggenda di sant’Eustachio e un racconto delle *Mille e una notte* ed uno ebraico del *Midrasch* che ne derivano (cfr. per es. *Gesta Romanorum*, 110; *Vite dei Santi Padri*, IV 49-53; *Legenda aurea*, 161 e anche 130 sant’Egidio; *Arabian Nights*, a cura di Smithers, Benares 1894, IX, pp. 50 e 213 sgg.; e in gen. A. MONTEVERDI, *La leggenda di Santo Eustachio*, in «Studi medievali», III, 1909, pp. 169 sgg.); la storia di san Clemente Papa volgarizzata già nel Trecento (Bologna 1863) e che è narrata anche nei Vangeli apocrifi (Petrus, 13); la storia di Sir Isumbras (*Thornton Romances*, London 1844); i *cantari* di *Carduino* (ed. Rajna, Bologna 1873), della *Bella Elena*, di *Fierabraccia*, il *Cantare dell’Apollonio di Tiro* (Venezia 1455, o i suoi antecedenti latini: per questi testi e l’eventuale conoscenza che il B. ne poté avere, cfr. V. BRANCA, *Il cantare trecentesco* cit.); e perfino i soliti romanzi greco-bizantini. Ma tutti i riscontri sono vaghi e poco convincenti. Anche lo sfondo storico – a parte quello vago e generico delle lotte tra Svevi, Aragonesi e Angioini, tanto caro al B. – sembra quasi tutto di fantasia (B. ZUMBINI, *Di alcune novelle del B. ecc.*, in «Atti R. Acc. della Crusca», 1903-904); ma tuttavia qualche particolare, come vedremo, conserva forse lontani riflessi di dati storici (cfr. note seguenti). Nessun valore hanno, naturalmente, le costruzioni di qualche scrittore napoletano, basate chiaramente sulla novella del B. (per es. F. CAMPANILE, *L’Armi overo insegne de’ Nobili*, Napoli 1610, p. 107; G. A. SUMMONTE, *Historia della città e regno di Napoli*, Napoli 1748, II, p. 383). Per gli elementi popolari e novellistici cfr. Thompson, N 251,730; Rotunda, B 580 sgg., 590 sgg., N 251,730: e anche T 31.1; H 51.1.

My translation:

> One cannot even indicate precise and significant antecedents of this novella.  The legend of Saint Eustace, a tale of the *One Thousand and One Nights* and a Hebrew story of the *Midrasch* that derive from it have been cited from time to time (cf. for example *Gesta Romanorum*, 110; *Vite dei Santi Padri*, IV 49-53; *Legenda aurea*, 161 and also 130 Sant'Egidio; *Arabian Nights*, edited by Smithers, Benares 1894, IX, pp. 50 and 213 ff .; and in gen. A. MONTEVERDI, *La leggenda di Santo Eustachio*, in "Studi medievali", III, 1909, pp. 169 sgg.); the story of San Clemente Papa already popularized in the fourteenth century (Bologna 1863) and which is also narrated in the apocryphal Gospels (Petrus, 13);  the story of Sir Isumbras (*Thornton Romances*, London 1844);  the *cantari* of *Carduino* (ed. Rajna, Bologna 1873), of the *Bella Elena*, of *Fierabraccia*, the *Cantare dell'Apollonio di Tiro* (Venice 1455, or its Latin antecedents: for these texts and the possible knowledge that B. could have, see V. BRANCA, *Il cantare trecentesco* cit.); and even the usual Greek-Byzantine novels. But all these evidences are vague and unconvincing. Even the historical background — apart from the vague and generic one of the struggles between the Suebi, Aragonese and Angevins, so dear to Boccaccio — seems almost entirely fictional (B. ZUMBINI, *Di some novelle del Boccaccio etc.*, in "Atti della Reale Accademia della Crusca", 1903-904); but however some details, as we shall see, preserve perhaps distant reflections of historical data (see the following notes). Of course, the constructions of some Neapolitan writers, clearly based on the novella of Boccaccio (for example F. CAMPANILE, *L'Armi overo insigne de' Nobili*, Naples 1610, p. 107; G. A. SUMMONTE, *Historia della città e regno di Napoli*, Naples 1748, II, p.  383).  For popular and short story elements, cf.  Thompson, N 251.730;  Rotunda, B 580 ff., 590 ff., N 251.730: and also T 31.1;  H 51.1.